# Is this setup necessary for every view?

Tags: express, webpack

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/server/views/index.pug',
      title: 'DEMO'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/server/views/login.pug',
      title: 'DEMO'
    }),
```

When using Webpack with Express is this kind of setup really necessary for every view?  A new `HtmlWebpackPlugin` for every view — login page, setting, home etc. (There are 7 in total). The `Webpack` assets will need to be injected into every page. This type of setup seems awful — I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. And technically you would want to limit your entry point to only load the JavaScript entries for that page!

The alternative here is to return an array of configs instead! Less duplicate code, less hassel!

I have answered a similar question here: **[Config on one or more entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059587/config-on-one-or-more-entry/56068777#56068777)**