# Config on one or more entry

Tags: webpack

I want to apply optimization on some entries, not all.

Is there a way to do it ?

For example :

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/client.js',
    server: './src/server.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader:['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: 'public/index.html' },
    ])
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entrypoint => `runtime_${entrypoint.name}`,
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/dist',
    contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
    hot: true,
  }
};
```

I want to apply optimization only on client (app) entry, not on server.

I can duplicate exports, creating one for my client app, and one for my server, but i will duplicate every modules, rules, plugins and other configurations that will evolves ! so bad scalibility.

I search for something but found nothing... I don't how and where, I thought I could do this with a

```js
only : 'app',
```

but I cannot find it again, maybe this was in my dreams xD

btw, if you think i can upgrade my webpack.config, if you have any suggestions, feel free to share !

Thx all !

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on an isomorphic setup here, (as it looks). You would want to use two separate webpack configurations.

There are some properties like [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target) which can only be set to one value and apply to your entire set of entries and compilation.

Luckily webpack does allow you to return an [array of configuration objects!](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#multicompiler)